# JsonResult Problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an ActionResult returning this :

```
return new JsonResult() { Data = new { isDeleted = isEntityDeleted } };
```

in javascript , the value returned by that ActionResult is  "{"isDeleted":true}" , which is an object called data, but if i try to access data.isDeleted i get undifined

What am i doing wrong?

**Edit**:

javascript code:-

```
 $.post('<%=Url.Content("~/Test/Delete")%>/',{entityID:idRow}, function(data) {
   if(data.isDeleted){
     //never gets here even though isDeleted is true
   } else{ } });
```

Comment: can you also post your javascript code?

Comment: javascript code:
$.post('<%=Url.Content("~/Test/Delete")%>/',{entityID:idRow},function(data){
                                                if(data.isDeleted){
                                                    //never gets here even though isDeleted is true
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    
                                                }
                                            });

Comment: @gigi: On Stack Overflow editing and refining questions as you get requests for more info is preferable, please don't provide info in comments especially code which is unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try post with the extra argument "json" at the end (last parameter).

cfr http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post